# Where to cleanup user-submitted data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, standards

Users can submit color palettes and I'd like to standardize the format of the hex codes submitted.

Is there a typical way to clean up/standardize this sort of user-submitted data?

In my case, there are four fields where users can enter a hex code. I ultimately want to store it without the pound sign. (So `#000000` to `000000`).

It's obviously easy to remove the pound sign, but *where* in the process it should be is what I'm not sure of.

Needs to be server-side as this data can be submitted via other methods than the browser (i.e. API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere!

You'll definitely want to clean it up server-side, as that's (presumably) where any sort of processing that expects consistently-formatted data to appear, and that's also where you'll be sanitizing user input (which you're doing, of course, right?). Don't trust anything from a remote source on a server!

A bit of client-side auto-formatting wouldn't hurt, though; use javascript to automatically format things and impress your users while doing it!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Javascript to sanitize the data before passing it through to *anything*? You should be able to easily evaluate the string and make adjustments there before submitting it to your controller/action.

Comment: Would rather not use Javascript here. This data, in the future, could be submitted via an API, so have to assume a browser isn't used.

Comment: I'd say it didn't answer the question.

Comment: @Shpigford you should specify in your question that Javascript is out of the question. That's sort of critical information.

Comment: Question updated. Though using javascript as the sole method of data-cleanup hardly seems like a valid solution.

Comment: @Shpigford it is a complement to whatever you do on the server side. I wouldn't recommend using it as one-stop cleanup. By the way, there's a lot of different ways to do this, but `before_save` in your model is probably a good way to go. If you need to reuse it, you might need to extend ActiveRecord.